# Excel copy-paste or sorting based on condition

Tags: excel, rows, copy-paste

I would like to copy-paste (or sort somehow) values based on specific criteria (for example I would like to have all values for student X stored in row 14).

The biggest problem is that 2 lists have different length, but the values still can have a match.

The picture below is pretty self-descriptive, hopefully.

[image: Example]

Comment: To start with, I would restructure your `How I would like to have it`. Instead of having the same name repeated 3 times in the same row, I would leave the names in the first column and bring `Actual list` next to `Obsolete list`. Apart from that, what have you tried so far? we can help you only if you provide what you have tried so far. We don't write the code for you

Comment: Regarding restructuring - no problems, this picture is not a holy-grail, but representation of overall idea. Like a mock-up.

Comment: Regarding things that was tried:
vlookup function (was not really helpful or probably I need more complex variant here); 
simple IF also not a case here;
complex custom sorting also was not helpful (I need to compare values with pivot table).

Comment: I see you have a value of `a5` in your `Obsolete list- Subject 2018` for `Alex` on how you want things to be but its not in that column on `how it looks`, what's the logic behind that? or is that just a typo? Also, is this data already in an excel file? or are you typing it in?

Comment: Just a typo for Alex. 
Data which is already in excel file - columns A,B,C
Data transferred (copy-paste from other file) - F till J.